# UnicodeDecodeError at / 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: django, utf-8, decode

This is a django project.

I have a simple view with 1 line in it : render_to_response('index.html'). And  this index.html contains characters like "öüä" which trigger the error  `'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1942-1944: invalid data` .

This is straightforward error which kind of says that it can't decode because this is not utf8 , yet i can't understand how to fix it . Where exactly should i specify something .

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`index.html` is most likely in a non-UTF-8 encoding, possibly [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). A hex editor is a good thing to use in these cases to examine how the `ö` et.c. are stored.

If `index.html` where in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), an `ö` would correspond to two bytes, `c3 b6`. If it is ISO-8859-1, it will be a single byte `f6`.

To solve this, either recode the file in UTF-8 or choose the right codec.

Comment: Thanks. You were right , my IDE had other encoding by default. Don't know why i didn't think of it =). After i changed it in IDE everything worked fine.